# Not being able to fetch user's data from backend due to blank screen

Tags: php, reactjs, authentication

In frontend I'm using ReactJs, and I've been trying to fetch the logged in user's data from backend (PHP) through axios.get, setting a condition to the user that they will be returned back to login page if nothing is returned from backend, and the condition of being returned back to login happens because the file that is responsible for processing the data from frontend is empty, thus nothing is returned.

I've set up the sessions, replaced $_SESSION[] with $_POST[], and also placed those code snippets at the top of the page:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors','1');
```

but nothing worked, and the errors are not being displayed. I have also tested in Postman, and it returns empty, but when I tested in x-www-form-urlencoded, with everything set up and written the key&values in any way possible, it returns the 400 error that all fields must be filled in.

Down below, I will be posting the code snippets of login and signup (where the user's input is processed to be sent to database).

**Login**

```
    $db = _db();

    try {

        $q=$db->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = :email");
        $q->bindValue(":email", $_POST["email"]);
        $q->execute();
        $row = $q->fetch();

        if(!empty($row)){

            if (password_verify($_POST["password"], $row["password"])) {

                $user = array(
                    "user_id" => $row["user_id"],
                    "first_name" => $row["first_name"],
                    "last_name" => $row["last_name"],
                    "email" => $row["email"],
                    "company" => $row["company"],
                    "phone_number" => $row["phone_number"],
                    "verified" => $row["verified"],
                    "token" => $row["token"],
                );


                header("Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
                http_response_code(200);
                echo json_encode($user);
                exit();

            } else {
                header("Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
                http_response_code(400);
                echo json_encode("Wrong email or password");
                exit();
            }
            
            } else {
                header("Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
                http_response_code(400);
                echo json_encode("User does not exist");
                exit();
        
            }
```

**Signup - set up $_SESSION here too as after confirming the account, I'm planning to redirect the user directly to dashboard**

```
            $q=$db->prepare("INSERT INTO users(user_id, first_name, last_name, company, email,     phone_number, password, forgot_password, token, verified) VALUES(:user_id, :first_name, :last_name, :company, :email, :phone_number, :password, :forgot_password, :token, :verified)");
            $q->bindValue(":user_id", null);
            $q->bindValue(":first_name", $firstName);
            $q->bindValue(":last_name", $lastName);
            $q->bindValue(":company", $company);
            $q->bindValue(":email", $email);
            $q->bindValue(":phone_number", $phoneNumber);
            $q->bindValue(":password", $passwordHash);
            $q->bindValue(":forgot_password", $forgotPass);
            $q->bindValue(":token", $token);
            $q->bindValue(":verified", false);
            $q->execute();

            $user_id = $db->lastInsertId();

            $to_email = $email;
            $subject = "Email subject";
            $message = "Click on the following link to verify your account:
                <a href='http://localhost/api/confirm_account.php?token=$token'>Confirm your account</a>";

            require_once(__DIR__."/emailVerification/send_email.php");

            $user = array(
                "user_id" => $_SESSION["user_id"] = $row["user_id"],
                "first_name" => $_SESSION["first_name"] = $row["first_name"],
                "last_name" => $_SESSION["last_name"] = $row["last_name"],
                "email" => $_SESSION["email"] = $row["email"],
                "company" => $_SESSION["company"] = $row["company"],
                "phone_number" => $_SESSION["phone_number"] = $row["phone_number"],
                "verified" => $_SESSION["verified"] = $row["verified"],
                "token" => $_SESSION["token"] = $row["token"],
            );
    

            header("Content-type: application/json");
            http_response_code(200);
            echo json_encode($user);
            exit();
        }
    }
```

**and this how I handle POST/GET requests in frontend**

```
const handleLogInSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();

    axios
      .post("http://localhost/api/login.php", {
        email: userInput.email,
        password: userInput.password,
      })
      .then((response) => {
        if (response.data) {
          navigate("/dashboard");
        } else {
          setErrorMessage("Login failed, try again");
        }
      })


 useEffect(() => {

    axios.get("http://localhost/api/login.php")
    .then((response) => {
      if(response.data){
        setUser(response.data);
        console.log(response.data)
      } else {
        console.log(response)
        navigate("/login");
      }
    });
}, [navigate]);
```

[The output of login.php file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XfL9R.png)

Let me know if you need to see the rest of frontend and backend's code.

**EDIT:**

Now, I'm able to see what's wrong with the code, still I keep getting redirected to the login page, even after getting the message **Logged in successfully**, only to see that axios.get retrieves nothing, only axios.post getting in action:

[image: POST request login]
[image: GET request login]

Answer (score 0):

The issue is you're sending `JSON` data from the frontend but are trying to extract it using `$_POST` which [according to the documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php) is meant for `x-www-form-urlencoded` or `multipart/form-data` form data.

Instead of sending JSON data you can send the data the backend is expecting which is a string of query params:

```
.post("http://localhost/api/login.php", new URLSearchParams({
  email: userInput.email,
  password: userInput.password,
}))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, Wesley, now I'm able to see what's actually wrong with the code, the login page looks fine, and the data is being retrieved in Postman, but still I keep getting redirected back to the login page because there's no data retrieved (in axios.post of login, there are the user's input, and appears that the login has been successful, but in axios.get, nothing is returned, therefore I get redirected out of dashboard(loggedIn screen), I will be editing the post to share the action when I try to log in.

Comment: The issue has been resolved by making a new PHP file to fetch all the columns in the database :)